# Installing Pik on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, command-prompt, pik

I tried installing pik today, following http://puneetpandey.com/tag/how-to-install-and-configure-pik-on-windows/. After typing in 'pik_install C:\tools' in the command prompt at the C: directory, it returns something like this:

> pik is installed
>
> The directory you installed to is not in the sytem path.
> C:\tools
>
> You will need to add it.

What is frustrating is that I already added C:\tools to my system variable.
Have spent some time searching on google for solutions but no luck. Please help

Comment: try restarting you system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Environment variables are not a system-wide thing but are stored per-process and inherited by child processes. So changing them in the System Settings will not have any immediate effect.

The guaranteed way for your changes to propagate is to restart your system. Otherwise you could try starting a process via <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.